# Value in list of values exists in elastic field list nest c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Could not solve the issue with elastic.

Given:

1. List with colors:
   `var colors_to_filter = ["red", "blue", "black"];`
2. Field colors in elasticsearch: `colors: ["green", "red", "black"]`

Task:

Get all products from elasticsearch with colors which has been defined in `colors_to_filter` list.
If any of the colors in `colors_to_filter` exists in elasticsearch `colors` field, return this product.

My current code which is not working:
(Take a look at this line):
   `.Bool(bl => bl.Filter(fl => fl.Terms( tr => tr.Field(fs => fs.Sizes.Suffix("keyword")).Terms(sizesList))`

```
  .Aggregations(a => a.Terms(sizesAggName, tt => tt.Field(o => o.Sizes.Suffix("keyword")))
                                .Max(priceAggNameMax, st => st.Field(o => o.SalePrice)))
  .TrackTotalHits()
  .Sort(p => GetSortType(sortType))
  .Index(GetIndexName())
  .From(from)
  .Size(size)
  .Query(q => q.Bool(b => GetQuery(mainCategory, subCategory, subSubcategory, term)))
  .PostFilter( ppf => ppf
  .Bool(bl => bl.Filter(fl => fl.Terms( tr => tr.Field(fs => fs.Sizes.Suffix("keyword")).Terms(sizesList))
  && ppf.Range(r => {
               r = r.Field(f => f.SalePrice);
               if (minPrice > 0) r = r.GreaterThanOrEquals((double)minPrice);
               if (maxPrice > 0) r = r.LessThanOrEquals((double)maxPrice);
               return r;
  })))));
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, you mean returned documents are not filtered correctly?

Comment: you are right, it was not filtered correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about elasticsearch. However the requirements seems clear:

First filter wich elements Color are in `colors_to_filter`. Then filter that results again by wich colors are *also* in `colors`. Only things that survive both filterings, are in the final result.

An optimsiation would be to cut those two lists down to one with all colors that are in both (wich would be "red" and "black"). Then use that amalgm array as filter. I am not sure wich kind of join this was again.

I am *guessing* elastisearch is supposed to do that optimisation automagically and this is a example to shows that to you? The exact order or even a preparatory join of two similar filters for performance? That is the only thing I could think being "elastic" with any search/filtering.

Comment: How to solve this issue without elastic NEST very clear, is not a problem. This is specific elasticsearch question. Anyway thank you for answer

Comment: @ShilovskoyeMoloko Single lines with a lot of `.` to chain calls are always a giant pain to debug. My advise is to never write them, as the only "price" for making them, is getting a **heck** of a time debugging them. I advise for as little as 1 operation per line, assigned to a temproary variable. The compiler will cut any underused tempoary variables in release builds, but for debugging they are worth their memory footprint | However I am unsure if that technique works for LINQ. Or LINQ equivalents. I think the evalulation was defered until teh result is actually used?

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
.Aggregations(a => a.Terms(sizesAggName, tt => tt.Field(o => o.Sizes.Suffix("keyword")))
                                .Max(priceAggNameMax, st => st.Field(o => o.SalePrice)))
  .TrackTotalHits()
  .Sort(p => GetSortType(sortType))
  .Index(GetIndexName())
  .From(from)
  .Size(size)
  .Query(q => q.Bool(b => GetQuery(mainCategory, subCategory, subSubcategory, term)))
  .PostFilter( ppf => ppf
  .Terms(tr =>
         {
             var tt = tr.Field(fs => fs.Sizes.Suffix("keyword"));
             return sizesList.Lenght() > 0 ? tt.Terms(selectedSizes) : tt;
         })
  && ppf.Range(r => {
             r = r.Field(f => f.SalePrice);
             if (minPrice > 0) r = r.GreaterThanOrEquals((double)minPrice);
             if (maxPrice > 0) r = r.LessThanOrEquals((double)maxPrice);
             return r;
  })));
```